# python serial gets data wrong

Tags: python, serialization, pyserial

I'm getting data from a microcontroller using serial. My problem is that if I tell the MCU to send data every 20mS some data gets corrupted. For example, if the MCU sends sin(time), you'd expect all the data to range from -1 to 1, but I end up getting a range of -1 to 100 (though most of what I get is between -1 to 1). Unfortunately, I won't always know what will be sent to the computer and it might vary a lot and I need to be able to trust what python tells me it is receiving.  Is there a time limit for Python and serial, if so what is it? Or is there a way to get data more reliably? I originally thought it was just a problem of the communication getting split into a few chunks (MCU sends: xxxx|xxxx|xxxx and python reads xxx and x|xxxx| and xxxx), which I've already dealt with. here is the code I'm using to get things from serial:

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as det
import os
import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import csv


######################### Functions #########################
## Find letter or character in string
def find(s, ch):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == ch]

## Find string in string
def find_str(s, char):
    index = 0

    if char in s:
        c = char[0]
        for ch in s:
            if ch == c:
                if s[index:index+len(char)] == char:
                    return index

            index += 1

    return -1

## Data saving
def DataSave(x, data):
    #for i in range(x):
     #   DATALISTS[i].append( int( a[ find(buffer,"|")[i] : find(buffer,"|")[i+1] ] ) )
    save = open(x, 'a')
    save.write(data + "\n")
    save.close()
######################### End #########################

######################### Filter #########################
First = True
Plot = True
NumberOfDataPoints = 1
currupt = []
TimeStamp = []
repeat = True

def GetDATA( file, path, port, baud ):
    File = True
    First = True
    Plot = True
    NumberOfDataPoints = 1
    currupt = []
    TimeStamp = []
    repeat = True
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout = 1)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    while repeat:
        x = ser.inWaiting()
        # only read when something is in buffer
        if x:

            # convert serial.read to a string and remove b' and ' from the beginning and end, respectively
            buffer = str (ser.read(x))
            buffer = buffer[2:][:-1]
            # Gets the time and appends to TimeStamp list
            TimeStamp.append (datetime.datetime.now())
            # Comfirm all data is received, if data is added to the buffer currupt
            lineEnd = ['\\r','\\n']
            # If there is no \r and/or \n in buffer, add buffer to currupt list
            if not any(word in buffer for word in lineEnd) :
                currupt.append(buffer)
            # If \r and/or \n in buffer print buffer 
            # If there is data in currupt list, buffer becomes data in currupt + buffer
            if any(word in buffer for word in lineEnd):
                if len(currupt) is not 0:
                    buffer = ''.join(currupt) + buffer
                del currupt[:]
                # Remove \r and \n from buffer
                while any(word in buffer for word in lineEnd):
                    for i in range(len(lineEnd)):
                        if lineEnd[i] in buffer:
                            buffer = buffer [: find_str(buffer, lineEnd[i] ) ]
                if First:
                    buffer = ''
                    del TimeStamp[:]
                    First = False
                    Plot = True
                # makes sure that there is something to write
                if len(buffer) is not 0:
                    # Set of one datapoint
                    if '|'  not in buffer:
                        if File is not False:
                            datafile=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), path, file)
                            DataSave(datafile, str(TimeStamp[0]) + '|' + buffer +'|')
                        #print(TimeStamp[0], buffer)
                        del TimeStamp[:]


## unused            
def SetDataPoints(file, path, port):
    GetDATA( file, path, port, False )
    return NumberOfDataPoints
```